# Pandas Dataframe multi merge, every comination

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe, merge, combinations

everyone!

I have a question relate in pandas dataframe multi merge, combination.

Plz, Check below data..

```
Rating csv
UserID ContentID Rating 
U-1      C-1       3
U-1      C-2       4
U-3      C-3       1
U-5      C-1       5

Content csv
Title ContentID Language
T-1      C-1      EN
T-2      C-2      EN
T-3      C-3      EN

User csv
UserID Age Gender
U-1    10    1
U-2    20    0
U-3    30    1
U-4    40    0 
U-5    50    1
U-6    60    0
U-7    70    1
```

I want Result

```
UserID ContentID Rating Title Language Age  Gender
U-1      C-1       3     T-1     EN     10     1
U-1      C-2       4     T-2     EN     10     1
U-1      C-3      NAN    T-3     EN     10     1
U-2      C-1      NAN    T-1     EN     20     0   
U-2      C-2      NAN    T-2     EN     20     0
U-2      C-3      NAN    T-3     EN     20     0
U-3      C-1      NAN    T-1     EN     30     1         
U-3      C-2      NAN    T-2     EN     30     1   
U-3      C-3       1     T-3     EN     30     1    
U-4      C-1      NAN    T-1     EN     40     0    
U-4      C-2      NAN    T-2     EN     40     0   
U-4      C-3      NAN    T-3     EN     40     0   
U-5      C-1       5     T-1     EN     50     1          
U-5      C-2      NAN    T-2     EN     50     1    
U-5      C-3      NAN    T-3     EN     50     1    
U-6      C-1      NAN    T-1     EN     60     0     
U-6      C-2      NAN    T-2     EN     60     0     
U-6      C-3      NAN    T-3     EN     60     0     
U-7      C-1      NAN    T-1     EN     70     1     
U-7      C-2      NAN    T-2     EN     70     1     
U-7      C-3      NAN    T-3     EN     70     1
```

Using three files,

It is the goal to match all kinds of Content that are relevant to the user.

Total DF Rows Size are UserID(User csv) Count * ContentID(Content csv) Count ( ex> Above 7 * 3 -> 21 rows)

All csv are relate. 
- Rating / Content -> ContentID(key)
- Rating / User -> UserID(key)

In other words, Result DataFrame is only remain rating zone(NAN), Other zone is none nan.

I use big csv( Real Size Content( 6000 ), User(220000 ) ) 
-> Total Result Rows will be about 1300000000

plz, help me..Thanks..

Comment: So [previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46441328/2901002) does not work? It seems question is same. Can you explain more?

Comment: as i told you, large data is not working..